# DHCP на Vlan не раздаёт адреса

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, dhcp, сеть

Имеется машина на ОС debian 9, на которой установлен Unifi controller, а так же имеется интерфейсы enp2s0(на интернет), enp4s0 (на нем создан vlan) из этого интерфейса идёт подключение на не контролируемый коммутатор, а уже из него идет подключение к тарелке Unifi, но при подключение клиента dhcp сервер не даёт адрес.
[image: ifconfig]
[image: interfaces]

Comment: subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option broadcast-address 192.168.10.255;
    option routers 192.168.10.1;
    authoritative;
    pool {
    range 192.168.10.10 192.168.10.254;}}

Comment: Всю дополнительную информацию добавляйте в вопрос, а не в комментарии.

Comment: Смотрите tcpdump'ом на enp4s0, проходят ли вообще тэгированные пакеты с запросами через мост и коммутатор.

Comment: посмотрел, все проходит.

Comment: Помотрите, присутствует ли вообще dhcpd. Ну и к тому же tcpdump'у: вдруг там и ответы видны?

Comment: на интерфейсе enp4s0 точкам доступа раздаются адреса, но вот почему-то на vlan не хочет раздавать клиентам.

Answer (score 0):

В `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-sever` отредактируйте строку INTERFACES, добавив в неё vlan10. После этого перезапустите dhcpd.

Comment: /etc/default/isc-dhcp-sever изначально при настройке "vlan10" был добавлен.